# Is it possible to develop a Facebook app that filters updates out of a feed?

Tags: facebook

Namely, does the Facebook API make this possible?  I'd like to leave my news feed intact, but remove posts that meet some criteria for things I don't want to see (e.g., don't show me anything that sounds like Dick Cheney might have said it).  Does the Facebook API allow apps to customize a user's normal news feed?  I spent a few minutes looking at the Facebook developer pages, but didn't see any direct answers to my question, so I was hoping some developers who were experienced with Facebook's API could help me here.

Before anyone mentions it, I don't want to just hide updates from those users.  They may post other updates that I want to see, so I'd prefer to filter out updates based on content.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Greasemonkey script called "[Facebook Purity](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/44459)" which does this. You could probably look at the source and alter it to your specifications.

Comment: Not *exactly* what I'm looking for since I'd have to install Greasemonkey and the script on every computer that I access Facebook from, but it could be a nice compromise if I can modify it to suit my needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the news feed into a database on your site then use code to parse whether or not to display it.

Comment: So my app can control what gets displayed in a facebook user's news feed when they go to their facebook home page?  That's what I need to know.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible but only if all your friends decide to add your application! otherwise you may be not able to access their feeds.

Its been a while since i used Facebook SDK so this may have changed.

Comment: Hmmm, that would be socially awkward, wouldn't it?  So they'd need to add my app in order for me to prevent their updates from showing up in my own news feed?  That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

The API provides very little news feed integration, and no you can't use the api to prevent news feed items from showing up in a users feed. All you can do is post and get, and you can only post 10 items a day, "significant" interactions. The Facebook API wasn't designed to enhance or alter the core Facebook experience, it was designed to allow developers to create third party apps that add to Facebook within a very limited and tightly controlled sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

[The Linq to facebook](http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/linq-to-fql-facebook-query-language/) project looks quite interesting and may allow you to do what you are asking (if using .NET 3.5). My apologies for a link to such a pink website ;-)